# Incrementing top value on repeating elements

Tags: jquery, css, each

I have an unknown number of `div`'s with class of `result`, I need each dive to have its `top` value increased by `8em` each time.

So the first `div.result` will have `top: 0em`, the second `top: 8em`, the third `top: 16em` and so on.

I thought this little bit of code might work:

```
var top = 0

$('div.result').each(function() {
    $('div.result').css('top', top+"em");
    top+8;
});
```

But unfortunately all `div.result`'s have `top: 0em`, the increment doesn't happen. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to assign the `top+8`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var top = 0

$('div.result').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top', top+"em");
    top = top + 8;
});
```

set top to `top + 8` or add 8 each time like this : `top += 8;`

Another approach :

```
var top = -8;
$('.result').css('top', function () {
    return (top += 8) + 'em';
});
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Kinda getting there, though now all of them have a top value of `136em`. I'm assuming this is counting all of them, (Adding 8 each time) then putting that final value on all elements?

Comment: Changed it, you need to use this !